# jQuery Live event binding

Tags: jquery

I have requirement like i will dynamically get a set of divs having random id's from my web service. And once it is added to my html i would like to bind some events to the id's. now my problem is if i am binding the event using for loop over the array of ID, when the scope of the loop finishes the events scope get destroyed.

ex:

```
var arrID={'1','2','3'};
for(var d in arr)
{
   arrID.live("click",function() {});
}

//scope of for loop finishes here, hence the scope of click also.
```

How to overcome this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't bind a click event to a JavaScript object. It has to be bound to a JQuery DOM object. Try this:

```
var arrID=['1','2','3'];

$.each(arrID, function(index, value) { 
    $('#' + value).live('click',function(){
        // Do something
    });
});
```

Here's a working demo. Notice only the first 3 created divs have the bound event: http://jsfiddle.net/FxwpC/

Answer (score 1):

You probably want something like this:

```
$("#my-id-name-" +d).live("click", function() {
    $(this).doSomeThing();
});
```

Comment: Yes and just add the hash to the beginning of the selector

Answer (score 0):

```
var arrID=['1','2','3'];
for(var d in arrID)
{
   $("#"+d).live("click",function() {});
}
```